# Prevent UITableViewCells from creating as you scroll down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a mail screen using which visually resembles the iOS native email app. It looks like this (*Both images are of the same screen. First one is the top half and the second one is the rest of it*).

[image]

[image]

The difference is my mail screen has more custom fields in addition to normal **To**, **Cc**, **Subjet** fields.

I'm using a `UITableViewController` to create this. Below is a code snippet which creates a cell (*For each cell it's pretty much the same*).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tokenTableView:(TITokenTableViewController *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,320);
    UIView *contentSubview = nil;

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierSubject];
        if(!self.txtSubject) {

            self.txtSubject = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
            self.txtSubject.frame = CGRectMake(10, cell.frame.size.height / 2 - self.txtSubject.font.lineHeight / 2, tableView.tableView.bounds.size.width, 30);

            self.txtSubject.placeholder = @"Subject";
            [self setupMailData:indexPath.row];
        }
    contentSubview = self.txtSubject;
}
```

Say, I open up a draft. All the details in the input fields are filled and without changing anything, I hit send and it crashes the app. I know what's causing this. The problem is that normally the cells that are under the viewable portion of the screen gets created as you scroll down, right? But in this scenario, if I send it without scrolling down but those cells below the viewport don't exist thus it throws the error.

If I open the draft, scroll down and hit send, it works fine.

I need to know if there's a way to create all these cells at once. Even the cells that are below the viewport at first. Not depending on the user to scroll down.

I hope you have an idea about my situation. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Cells should only be used for viewing data. If sending causes your app to crash because a cell is off screen, then your design isn't correct. You should post the code for what you do when you hit send.

Comment: agree w @rdelmar--you should correctly handle the case where those cells don't exist

Comment: @rdelmar and @nielsbot : Thanks for the response and I agree. Unfortunately like rdelmar has predicted this app is full of architectural flaws like these. Send button's code doesn't really do much except building a URL with the parameters and firing it. The problem here is that the textfields at the bottom aren't just textfields. Wen you tap on them, it opens a `UIActionSheet` with a `UIPickerView` embedded inside. The user selects one from their and in that event, it retrieves an ID according to the selected textual value. These missing IDs are the reason for the error.

Comment: It's a long code file I hardly think it will do any good posting it here. But @rdelmar 's comment got me rethinking about this situation froma  different view. Now I'm looking for a way to retrive and store all the IDs even before the cells appearing. I'll post back with my results. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

follow steps:

1. Take uiscrollview and set scrollview frame as which you want to display.
2. Take uitableview as a subview of uiscrollview
3. set property `Scrolling Enabled` = NO (uncheck checkbox in .xib) of uitableview
4. call `reloaddata` method of uitableview
5. set tableview frame and contentsize of scrollview

   ```
   tblEmail.frame = CGRectMake(yourXPos, yourYPos, yourWidth, tblEmail.contentSize.height);
   scrollObj.contentSize = CGSizeMake(yourScrollWidth,tblEmail.contentSize.height+10);
   ```

so, the height of tableview is equal its contentsize. so, its create all cells at a time. and set contentsize of scrollview is equal tableview contentsize. so, the scrolling feature is worked like uitableview scrolling...

Comment: Actually I have a `UITableViewController`. Sorry I forgot to mention that in my question. Is it possible to do this with a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: no, it is not proper for uitableviewcontroller. but you use uiviewcontroller instead of uitableviewcontroller. after that perform this steps. this is the solution of your problem....

Answer (score 0):

Use a Storyboard, add a **UITableViewController and set the 'Content' to StaticCells**.
Then you can define all the cells and their content in the Storyboard. You can even wire stuff up to IBOutlets in your UITableViewController subclass and they will all be there for you when viewDidLoad is fired ...

When using a Storyboard your code for getting the ViewController looks like:

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Comment: Hi Mike, can you please tell me how to set the Content to StaticCells? Is there a property or something? I've looked in the Attribute Inspector but nothing there, it seems...

Comment: Yep it's in the Attributes inspector for the 'Table View' within the UITableViewController. Right at the top. Your options are Dynamic Prototypes or Static Cells.

Comment: hmm.... [This](http://i.imgur.com/pieAV8B.png) is my Xcode view but I don't see such an option. Weird.

Comment: AH, you know what I think it's only an option when using a Storyboard, not XIBs. Try a Storyboard instead.